# React-native installation issue

Tags: android, node.js, bash, react-native

Followed the setup steps from official site,I am not able to find react-natve command refer below console commands and its output:

```
Bhushans-MBP:node_modules bhushanraut$ npm install -g react-native-cli
/Users/bhushanraut/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/bhushanraut/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/Users/bhushanraut/.npm-packages/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.2.0 

Bhushans-MBP:node_modules bhushanraut$ react-native init AwesomeProject
-bash: react-native: command not found
```

Please help me to resolve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `/Users/bhushanraut/.npm-packages/bin/` directory is not added to global `PATH` variable.

You need add that to `PATH` variable.

Execute the below command in terminal

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

This will open the file in vi editor. Append the following line in that file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:'/Users/bhushanraut/.npm-packages/bin/'
```

Then save and close the file.

Execute the following command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now try executing `react-native init AwesomeProject` command. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps may be useful for react-native installation if you encounter any problem

Steps followed from the below URL
https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65

> npm install -g react-native-cli
>
> react-native init AwesomeProject
>
> cd AwesomeProject/
>
> ((if not exist "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle" mkdir "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle") && (echo org.gradle.daemon=true >> "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/gradle.properties"))
>
> react-native run-android

There was error unable to configure the gradle from @react-native-community/CLI-Platform-android

Hence navigate to AwesomeProject/node_modules, run the below command

> npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android

Finally build is executed successfully without any error

> react-native run-android

In another command prompt start the emulator

> C:\Users\tapzu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
> Nexus_6P_API_28
> C:\Users\tapzu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Nexus_6P_API_28